# Angular 5 nested http client observables return object

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, angular-httpclient

I am trying to create an observable response where I make one http call and then before returning the response, I make another http call to populate the return object of the first call as shown below.

```
getOrderWithItems(orderId: string, includes: Set<OrderInclude>): Observable<OrderDto> {
    return this.getOrder(orderId, includes)
      .map(order => {
        this.searchItems().subscribe(
          items => {
            order.items = items.results;
            return order;
          }
        )
      });
  }
```

The compiler gives an error: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Not sure how to get this to work. this.getOrder() and this.searchItems() both map http calls which return corresponding observables.

Answer (score 0):

Your *map* doesn't return anything. It only subscribes to another Observable.

For transforming one Observable into another (*getOrder* to *searchItems*), use one of the flat Operators. In your case, **switchMap** would fit:

```
this.getOrder(orderId, includes)
  .switchMap(order => 
    this.searchItems()
      .map(items => ({...order, items: items.results}))
  );
```

Comment: I always would recommend switchMap. Not mergeMap.
It is a very unusual scenario in which a subsequent request should not cancel when the source Observable emits the next time.