# Pass result of one RxJS observable into next sequential observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to do a basic chaining of RxJS HTTP calls where the first call is going to pass the ID of an object that was created server-side into the second call.  What I am observing with my implementation is that only the first call is made and the second chained call is never executed.

Below is roughly the code that I have.

First call:

```
createItem(itemData) {
  return this.http.post(createUrl, itemData)
    .map((res) => res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Second call:

```
addFileToItem(id, file): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(secondUrl + id, file)
    .map((res) => log(res))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Function defined mapping one call into the other:

```
createAndUpload(itemData, file): Observable<any> {
  return createItem(itemData, file)
    .map((res) => {
      if (file) {
        return addFileToItem(res.id, file);
      }
    });
}
```

And finally, where the observable is executed through a `subscribe()`:

```
someFunction(itemData, file) {
  createAndUpload(itemData, file)
    .subscribe(res => {
      log(res);
      //go do something else
    };
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101448/angular-5-nested-http-client-observables-return-object/49101645#49101645

Comment: Thank you @ZahiC.  I'm going to post an answer with the proper correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `createAndUpload` where `map` just turns the result from the first call into an Observable but you never subscribe to it.

So simply said you just need to use `mergeMap` (or `concatMap` in this case it doesn't matter) instead of `map`. The `mergeMap` operator will subscribe to the inner Observable and emit its result:

```
createAndUpload(itemData, file): Observable<any> {
  return createItem(itemData, file)
    .mergeMap((res) => {
      if (file) {
        return addFileToItem(res.id, file);
      }
      return Observable.empty(); // you can't return `undefined` from the inner Observable
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `map()` function doesn't actually return anything, meaning that an `Observable` object is not returned.  Instead, a transforming operator such as `mergeMap` is needed.

Here is the code that ended up working, also using the "newer" `.pipe()` operator.  The only place the code needed to be changed was in the Observable function where I defined the combination of the two separate Observables.  In order to access the `mergeMap` operator, don't forget to import it from `rxjs/operators`.

For a reason that I will eventually figure out, I couldn't access the `mergeMap` without the pipe...

```
createAndUpload(itemData, file): Observable<any> {
  return createItem(itemData, file)
    .pipe(
        mergeMap((res) => {
          if (file) {
            return addFileToItem(res.id, file);
          }
        })
     )
}
```